# PHP SQL integration

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am connected to my database.
Created a drop down-box. Which works fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<b>Customer Name : </b>" . "<select id='CustomerName' name='CustomerName'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['CustomerName'] . "'>" . $row['CustomerName'] . "</option>";
}
```

Now I am stuck trying to put the values from table Customer into an array
 Which looks like this:

```
 $types = array (
             'A' => 10.99,
             'B' => 4.99,
             'C' => 13.99);
```

What I intend to do is to create this array where,
Instead of A B C, there are CustomeName and CustomerPrice in place of the price.
The Customer table has

```
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+
| Customer_ID    | CustomerName    | CustomerPrice |
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+
|              1 | A               |     10.99     |
|              2 | B               |      4.99     |
|              3 | C               |     13.99     |
+----------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Please help

Comment: Does Customer_ID contain '1 2 3' or do you mean there are three records?

Comment: ID 1 is of A who's price is 10.99. So on it ID is not really needed

Comment: Post code of you mysql read and your result parsing algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically do the same thing you did with the drop down except to generate the array. You could do it in the same loop:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$array = array();
echo "<b>Customer Name : </b>" . "<select id='CustomerName' name='CustomerName'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $array[$row['CustomerName']] = $row['CustomerPrice'];
  echo "<option value='" . $row['CustomerName'] . "'>" . $row['CustomerName'] . "</option>";
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Before trying it will it work if I have arrays from multiple tables. for example $customer = array(); then another with the name $types array. I hope I am able to explain what I mean.

Comment: @J.Doe - I'm not sure I follow, but it would work for any table. However you would need to preform another query and while loop to iterate through results for another table.